# How Array work (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array is product

```
product[1][...]
product[2][...]
...
```

And I have a other array is hold.

My command:

```
hold['product'] = product;

for(i in product){
    delete product[i];
}

for(i in hold['product']){
    alert(i);
}
```

And Nothing happen. hold array doesn't have any element when I delete element of product array?

Answer (score 2):

That is expected behavior. Complex types such as arrays are passed by reference in JavaScript. So when you assign an array to another variable, you are really assigning the reference. In order to avoid it, you should assign a copy of the original.

Try:

```
hold['product'] = product.slice(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
var hold['product'] = product.slice();
```

It will create new copy of array on heap memory.So both array have their own copy

for more please check this one [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)